# Sum number of a tuple without use list

Tags: python, list, function

I have this function and it returns me the different operation that I need to do to get my results.

```
number=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
def addition_all(n, lst):
    if not n and not lst:  # base case 1: empty list = 0
        return [[]]
    if n < 0 or not lst:  # base case 2: unsolvable
        return []
    result = []
    head, *tail = lst
    for sol in addition_all(n-head, tail):  # recursion 1: use first element
        result.append([head] + sol)
    result.extend(addition_all(n, tail))
    return result
print(sumto(10,number))
```

It returns me :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [4, 6]]
```

But I would like that :

```
1+2=3
3+3=6
4+6=10
```

I would like recuperate the value of the addition  and after I want save my number ( who is 3 here) and add 3 with next value who is 3  .......

Here an example

```
number=[2,1,3,2,2]

number that I research : 5

solution with the function from before :
[2,1,2] [1,2,2]....
```

But me I would like that it returns me not a list but all different number that I can have  with the sum on this form :

```
2+1=3
3+3=6
6+2=8
8+2=10
2+3=5 !!!  I find my number so I can stop the function and it returns me :

2+3=5 !!
```

If you can help me, it could be very nice !!! Thanks for reading me !!